# How does "Inodes per group" and "lazy_itable_init" flag relate to the "Inode count" value in an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, inode, mkfs, e2fsprogs

I am trying to root cause a customer case where 2 Identical drives, formatted with the same command, led to a difference of ~55GB in total disk space due to additional Inode overhead.

I want to understand

1. The math on how 2x`Inodes per group` translates to 2x`Inode count`
2. How does `Inodes per group` get set when `lazy_itable_init` flag is used

**Environment:**

The 2 drives are on 2 identical hardware servers, running on the same exact OS.
Here are the details of the 2 drives (Sensitive info redacted):

Drive A:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HPE
Product:              <strip>
Revision:             HPD4
Compliance:           SPC-5
User Capacity:        7,681,501,126,656 bytes [7.68 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is resource provisioned, LBPRZ=1
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      <strip>
Serial number:        <strip>
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Mon Apr 25 07:39:27 2022 GMT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
```

Drive B:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HPE
Product:              <strip>
Revision:             HPD4
Compliance:           SPC-5
User Capacity:        7,681,501,126,656 bytes [7.68 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is resource provisioned, LBPRZ=1
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      <strip>
Serial number:        <strip>
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Mon Apr 25 07:39:23 2022 GMT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
```

The command run to format the drive is:

`sudo mke2fs -F -m 1 -t ext4  -E lazy_itable_init,nodiscard /dev/sdc1`

**The issue:**

The `df -h` output for Drives A and B respectively shows DriveA with size 6.9T vs Drive B with size 7.0T:

```
/dev/sdc1       6.9T   89M  6.9T   1% /home/<strip>/data/<serial>
...
/dev/sdc1       7.0T  3.0G  6.9T   1% /home/<strip>/data/<serial>
```

**Observations:**

- fdisk output on both drives show they both have identical partitions.

DriveA:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 7681.5 GB, 7681501126656 bytes, 15002931888 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 8192 bytes / 8192 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70627C8E-9F97-468E-8EE6-54E960492318


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048  15002929151      7T  Microsoft basic primary
```

DriveB:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 7681.5 GB, 7681501126656 bytes, 15002931888 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 8192 bytes / 8192 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 702A42FA-9A20-4CE4-B938-83D3AB3DCC49


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048  15002929151      7T  Microsoft basic primary
```

- `/etc/mke2fs.conf` contents are identical on both systems, so no funny business here:

```
================== DriveA =================
[defaults]
        base_features = sparse_super,filetype,resize_inode,dir_index,ext_attr
        enable_periodic_fsck = 1
        blocksize = 4096
        inode_size = 256
        inode_ratio = 16384

[fs_types]
        ext3 = {
                features = has_journal
        }
        ext4 = {
                features = has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,uninit_bg,dir_nlink,extra_isize,64bit
                inode_size = 256
        }
...
================== DriveB =================
[defaults]
        base_features = sparse_super,filetype,resize_inode,dir_index,ext_attr
        enable_periodic_fsck = 1
        blocksize = 4096
        inode_size = 256
        inode_ratio = 16384

[fs_types]
        ext3 = {
                features = has_journal
        }
        ext4 = {
                features = has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,uninit_bg,dir_nlink,extra_isize,64bit
                inode_size = 256
        }
```

- If we take a diff between the tune2fs -l output for both drives, we see `Inodes per group` on DriveA are 2x DriveB
- We also see `Inode count` on DriveA is 2xDriveB (Full diff [HERE](https://www.diffchecker.com/yvhZcxGm))

```
DriveA:
    Inode count:              468844544
    Block count:              1875365888
    Reserved block count:     18753658
    Free blocks:              1845578463
    Free inodes:              468843793
    ...
    Fragments per group:      32768
    Inodes per group:         8192
    Inode blocks per group:   512
    Flex block group size:    16
    
DriveB:
    Inode count:              234422272 <----- Half of A
    Block count:              1875365888
    Reserved block count:     18753658
    Free blocks:              1860525018
    Free inodes:              234422261
    ...
    Fragments per group:      32768
    Inodes per group:         4096 <---------- Half of A
    Inode blocks per group:   256  <---------- Half of A
    Flex block group size:    16
```

- From [How to calculate the "Inode blocks per group" on ext2 file system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410577) I understand `Inode blocks per group` is a result of `Inodes per group`
- From the mke2fs code ([Source](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/misc/mke2fs.c#L415)), `Inodes per group` value seems to be called in the `write_inode_tables` function only when `lazy_itable_init` is provided:

```
write_inode_tables(fs, lazy_itable_init, itable_zeroed);
...
static void write_inode_tables(ext2_filsys fs, int lazy_flag, int itable_zeroed)
...
    if (lazy_flag)
        num = ext2fs_div_ceil((fs->super->s_inodes_per_group - <--------- here
                       ext2fs_bg_itable_unused(fs, i)) *
                      EXT2_INODE_SIZE(fs->super),
                      EXT2_BLOCK_SIZE(fs->super));
```

If we take the difference in inode count and multiply it by the constant inode size (256) we get `(468844544-234422272)*256 = 60012101632 bytes` ~55GiB of extra inode overhead.

1. Can anyone help me the math on how Inode count increased to 2x when `Inodes per group` increased to 2x?
2. Does `lazy_itable_init` have an impact at runtime that decides the value of `Inodes per group`, if so how can we understand what value will it set?
   (This flag was the only reference to s_inodes_per_group in the code)

Comment: Were the filesystems formatted with the same version of mke2fs?

Comment: I didn't think of checking that unfortunately, but we redeployed the systems again and now seeing consistent behaviors. I will mark it as solved for now.
Edit: Not sure how to mark your commend as the answer lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the difference in these 2 cases was a difference in the e2fsprogs version - 1.42.9 & 1.45.4.  I didn't think of checking that and only relied on mke2fs.conf file. Apologies for this obvious miss and thanks @lustreone for suggesting.

I am still curious to know the math relating to Inodes per group and Inode count.